# An Error for installing AVR development platform for mac

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, terminal, arduino

I tried to install AVR development platform for mac from this site

http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/setup-mac.html
 **Option 3. Old style, 'by hand' compilation**

but I have this error, I have Intel processor on macBookair and I don't know why there is a error for PowerPC

Here is the error

****Launch of "as" failed: the PowerPC architecture is no longer supported.

make[3]: *** [libgcc/./_mulqi3.o] Error 1

make[2]: *** [stmp-multilib] Error 2

make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2****

is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a lot of steps in that.

I suggest you do a quick sanity check. Download the [Arduino IDE](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software)

It also contains the AVR toolchain, and try to 'verify' (the left most button) the 'Blink' program

```
File->Examples->1. Basics->Blink)
```

If that verifies, recheck your install; it is likely you can make it work.

If it doesn't verify, and gives the same sort of error, you have deeper problems.

Edit 1:
Okay, so Arduino IDE works.

There is a toolchain which will work for AVR inside the Arduino package, in folder:

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin
```

So you could use that if you want to do 'by hand' compilation.

wrt your AVR development platform installation, I see that article, is "step 2 Install OSX-AVR" gave two options, one is "OSX-AVR-JAN07-PPC.dmg" did you install that? That is the wrong one. That would explain the error messages you are getting.  You will need to uninstall it, and install the correct one.

Frankly, you might be better with the tools inside the Arduino package, the ones at `http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxavr/files/osxavr/OSX-AVR-JAN07/` are more than 5 years old. The ones inside the Arduino IDE are likely to be much newer.

Comment: I try to do everything from first but still error but another one :ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cc1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: @Elnaz Shahmehr - I don't think I understand, and I don't know what to suggest. The error message look like the loader (ld) which brings together all of the pieces into a program, is trying to make an x86 program. That is almost like it is trying to make a program for the Mac. That might be happening because it is finding the wrong version of programs. It is finding the Mac versions, and not the AVR versions. I think it is worth you seraching the web for those words with the words "AVR" ort "AVR development" or "AVR ld"